# Ruby RSS/Atom creation - including content

Tags: ruby, rss, atom-feed

I am creating an Atom feed using ruby's stdlib `rss` library.  This library is essentially undocumented , but I have it working using the example provided on [this page](http://apidock.com/ruby/RSS):

```
require 'rss'

rss = RSS::Maker.make("atom") do |m|

    m.channel.author  = "Steve Wattam"
    m.channel.updated = Time.now
    m.channel.about   = "http://stephenwattam.com/blog/"
    m.channel.title   = "Steve W's Blog"

    storage.posts.each do |p|
        m.items.new_item do |item|
            item.link    = p.link
            item.title   = p.title
            item.updated = p.edited
            item.pubDate = p.date
            item.summary = p.summary
        end
    end
 end
```

This works fine.  I am unable, however, to add a content element.  There is no such thing as `item.content=`, and I can't seem to find any example code online---a browse of the source indicates that `content` *is* stored in the item ([docs here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS/Maker/Atom/Entry/Items/Item.html)), but I lack the knowledge to tease it out.

Does anyone know how I might go about adding a content element?

Incidentally, I'm aware other libraries exist to do this, but would ideally like to get this working without requiring any gems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By digging through the source of the library, I've discovered that `item.content` yields an object of type `RSS::Maker::Atom::Feed::Items::Item::Content`.  It's possible to set the content on that object:

```
item.content.content = 'text to set as content'
```

This object also responds to `#xml_content`.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anymore. That library is a mess.